# Inserting PHP code into the InnerHTML of a SELECT Tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a function when called, will write PHP code into my document.

For example (original code) .

```
<select name="impressora" class="form-control">
<option value="selecione">Selecione1...</option><?php foreach($result as 
$prod){?><option value="<?php echo $prod['nome'] ?>"><?php echo 
$prod['nome'] ?></option><?php } ?></select>
```

The SELECT-Tag above connects to my database to retrieve the data.

When i try using a JavaScript function to insert the retrieved data (seen below)

```
function impressora_select(){
var imp = document.getElementById("impressora_div").innerHTML = "<select name='impressora' class='form-control'><option value='selecione'>Selecione2...</option><?php foreach($result as $prod){?><option value='<?php $prod['nome'] ?>'><?php $prod['nome'] ?></option><?php } ?></select>"

  }
```

All that is returned(inserted) is a select option called " Selecione2..."
How do i make this function insert data from my database into my document via innerHTML?

Thanks.

---

Update with changes from Hasan Delibas.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jque‌​‌​
ry.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$.ajax
({ url: "functions3.php?get=getvalue",
 }) 
 .done(function( data ) {
  var imp = document.getElementById("impressora_div").innerHTML = data; }); 
  </script> 
  functions3.php -> select name='impressora' class='form-control'><option 
  value='selecione'>Selecione2...</option><?php foreach($result as $prod){?>
 <option value='<?php $prod['nome'] ?>'><?php $prod['nome'] ?></option><?php 
 } ?></select>
```

But is retuning this error.

```
 portnew.php:5 GET 



portnew.php:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at portnew.php:7
(anonymous) @ portnew.php:7
porntnew.php:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at portnew.php:42
```

Comment: PHP is processed on the server side, Javascript on the client side. This will not work.

Comment: You are welcome. You must using ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
In web browser side if you want to use mysql. You must use ajax.

Comment: but , i want only write the function inside innerhtml at my div . why this cannot work ?

Comment: Php using on server side. Web browser can not run php codes. If you want to click a <section> after change second </section>. You must post some form your <section> data to any php file . And php file return xml file. you can see datas.

Answer (score 0):

You must use ajax.

First create new .php file for change inside #impressora_div

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.ajax({
  url: "newPhpFile.php?get=getvalue",
})
  .done(function( data ) {
      var imp = document.getElementById("impressora_div").innerHTML = data;
  });
</script>
```

You can not use php web browser side. You but you can call .php file with ajax.